# Keep invoice sum right without losing performance?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Invoice](
    [InvoiceID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [TotalSumBeforeTax] [decimal](12, 2) NOT NULL,
    [TotalSumAfterTax] [decimal](12, 2) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InvoiceItem](
    [InvoiceItemID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [AmountBeforeTax] [decimal](12, 2) NOT NULL,
    [AmountAfterTax] [decimal](12, 2) NOT NULL
)
```

The Invoice table holds a calculated sum of all the `InvoiceItems` that refer to that Invoice.

I need help figuring out the best practice to keep the Invoice sum correct without losing performance.

**Calculated column?**

If I use a calculated column for `TotalSumBeforeTax` and `TotalSumAfterTax` in the Invoice table, that fetches values via a function from the `InvoiceItem` table, it's not persisted and will be very slow, since I have hundreds of thousands of rows in the `InvoiceItem` table.

**Trigger?**

I also thought about using a trigger on the `InvoiceItem` table and then updating the Invioce `TotalSumBeforeTax` `TotalAfterBeforeTax` columns.

**What to do?**

Is there a way to always keeping the `TotalSumBeforeTax` and `TotalSumAfterTax` columns up-to-date with minimal impact on performance when listing many rows of the Invoice table?

Comment: If you want to avoid a query which would always need to iterate over all to generate a rolling sum, then, as you suggested, a trigger is one way to go.

Comment: With the right indexes a computed column should perform just fine even with a lot of rows in the table. Although a sub-query when accessing the invoice table will probably perform better than a computed column based on a function.

Comment: Trigger won't scale and can impact performance much harder than calculated column. Your performance are impact by choosing GUID as a row identifier.

Comment: How many rows are you calling a lot anyway? SQL Server is an enterprise solution, it can handle a good few rows :) While its obviously good to keep performance in mind, don't try and solve a problem that isn't yet a problem.

Comment: I agreed with @Dale Burrell. My experience is with computed columns is positive. In addition, as I wrote, your table design with GUID might cause page split. So, changing GUID to BIGINT will improve your performance, as well as good indexing.

Comment: **Invoice** sums aren't supposed to be modified after the fact. A calculated column would be inappropriate. The total should be calculated when the invoice is "finalized" whatever that means for your country's/state's tax code. Calculating the ssum of even a few thousand invoice items (eg detailed invoice for an airplane) doesn't take long as long as the table has the proper indexes

Comment: Besides, an invoice sum could be affected by taxes and fees applied to the entire invoice, not just the individual items

Comment: @DaleBurrell ... in my RL project, I have several "InvoiceItem" tables that I need to sum up and with like 320.000 rows in just one of the tables, it takes like 2-3 minutes to show all records in the "Invoice" table with with sub-quering the "InvoiceItem" tables. I need to speed this up.

Comment: @MojoDK under what circumstances do you need to query "all invoices" at the same time?

Comment: And what indexes do you have on the table? The number of rows you are quoting isn't enough to be that slow so long as you have the correct indexes.

Comment: And have you tried the 2 solutions below? If so how did they perform?

Comment: @DaleBurrell - my RL project is a danish Insurance system, and the customer is able in many ways to get some of the money of the "invoice" in return both before and after it is paid, so to calculate if the invoice is fully paid, I need to sum up all the amounts that have been performed on this particular invoice (sry for my English) :)

Comment: Still with the correct indexes that shouldn't be slow.

Comment: I think as @PanagiotisKanavos mentioned, at some point an invoice should be finalised. Maybe when the final payment is received, and then a flag "IsPaid" might be set. After which time you wouldn't allow editing of the invoice or the associated invoice items, and as part of that you could update the invoice total amount. Then you would only be querying InvoiceItems for unpaid invoices which should perform well.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that you shouldn't keep these columns at all. Just create an index on the `InvoiceItem` table that will have the `InvoiceID` and include the `AmountBeforeTax` and `AmountAfterTax` columns, and calculate when needed using a simple `sum` and `group by` query:

```
SELECT InvoiceID
    , SUM(AmountBeforeTax) AS TotalSumBeforeTax
    , SUM(AmountAfterTax) AS TotalSumAfterTax
FROM dbo.InvoiceItem
GROUP BY InvoiceID
```

As a rule of thumb, things that can easily be computed shouldn't be stored - because it's easier to compute than to synchronize the stored values.

BTW, if there's a tax involved shouldn't it be `price` and not `amount`?

Comment: In my RL project, I have several table the "Invoice" table has to sum up. One of the tables have like 320.000 rows and the Invoice table is like 60.000 rows. To use "sum" in a view will take like 2-3 minutes to show all the records with all the right indexes. I would like to speed that up.

Comment: 320,000 rows is really not a big table in SQL Server's standards... a simple group by query like this shouldn't take that much time. You're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr; Start with a view then if/when necessary modify to an indexed view.**

I would initially create a view on your Invoice table e.g.

```
create view dbo.InvoiceView
as
SELECT I.* -- Don't actually use *, spell out all your columns
  , (select SUM(AmountBeforeTax) from dbo.InvoiceItem II where II.InvoiceId = I.InvoiceId) AS TotalSumBeforeTax
  , (select SUM(AmountAfterTax) from dbo.InvoiceItem II where II.InvoiceId = I.InvoiceId) AS TotalSumAfterTax
FROM dbo.Invoice I;
```

with (at least) an index on `dbo.InvoiceItem.InvoiceId`.

I imagine this will perform pretty well for quite some time. Then when the performance drops off, turn it into an [indexed view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-2017) by creating a clustered index on it e.g.

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CX_InvoiceId
   ON dbo.InvoiceView (InvoiceID); -- And any other relevant columns
GO
```

Which has a similar effect under the hood to creating a trigger but you don't have to manage it.

Comment: This (indexing view) sounds interesting - I will try and set it up and let you know the result.