# Multiple computed columns from same child table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Invoice]
(
    [InvoiceID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InvoiceItem]
(
    [InvoiceItemID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [PriceBeforeTax] [decimal](12, 2) NOT NULL,
    [PriceAfterTax] [decimal](12, 2) NOT NULL
)
```

In the `Invoice` table, I want two computed columns:

- TotalSumBeforeTax
- TotalSumAfterTax

I'm fetching the computed columns from a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufnGetInvoiceSum
     (@InvoiceID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
RETURNS @T TABLE (SumBeforeTax DECIMAL(16, 2) NOT NULL,
                  SumAfterTax DECIMAL(16, 2) NOT NULL) 
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @sumBeforeTax DECIMAL(16, 2)
    DECLARE @sumAfterTax DECIMAL(16, 2)

    SELECT @sumBeforeTax = SUM(PriceBeforeTax), 
           @sumAfterTax = SUM(PriceAfterTax) 
    FROM InvoiceItem 
    WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID

    INSERT INTO @T (SumBeforeTax, SumAfterTax) 
    VALUES (@sumBeforeTax, @sumAfterTax)

    RETURN
END
```

But how can I in the Invoice computed columns fetch data from the `ufnGetInvoiceSum` in one call?

I don't want to call `ufnGetInvoiceSum` to get `TotalSumBeforeTax` and then call it again to get `TotalSumAfterTax`.

Can two computed columns get data from the same child table in one call?

I'm not sure I'm good enough to express myself.

:)

Comment: Short answer - no. You are a serial pre-optimizer. You have attempted to prematurely "optimize" your queries (without reason) and you now see/assume that your optimization path also needs further optimization. Don't do this at all. But if you think you need to do something like this, then follow the suggestions from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58265308/keep-invoice-sum-right-without-losing-performance) - which is still waiting for your response/answer selection.

Comment: I could not include the question in this post properly in my previous post - and to answer my previous post, I need to know if the question in this post is possible. Thanks.

Comment: As somebody who seems overly concerned about performance you really need to evaluate your function here. You have a multi-statement table valued function which is often even slower than a scalar function. Worse is that there is no need for multiple statements at all. This should be a single select statement and then it will be an inline table valued function which is exponentially faster than the multi-statement version you have.

Comment: @SeanLange .. in my RL function, I need to calculate data from several tables also using cursors etc., so unfortunately it can't be single select statement. Sry I wasn't clear enough, that the above is just a test sample.

Comment: Oh lord....do yourself a favor and don't put cursors in a multi-statement table valued function. You would actually be better off using a scalar if you have to use cursors. But I highly doubt you need cursors. Almost any data retrieval process can be done set based. Cursors are good for some administrative tasks and sending personalized emails. Otherwise they should be avoided like the plague.